# Javascript Chrome API- cannot read property of undefined

Tags: javascript, sockets, google-chrome

I'm writing a little javascript application trying to use the Chrome sockets API. The code doesn't seem terribly relevant, though, because I'm getting an error on the very first line:

```
var socket = chrome.sockets.udp;
```

On that line, I get an Uncaught TypeError: cannot read property 'udp' of undefined. So chrome.sockets isn't being defined for some reason, but for the life of me I can't seem to figure out what. Is there something I need to include or import to use Chrome APIs? The API doc hasn't been helpful in that regard.

EDIT: background.js file:

```
var socket = chrome.sockets.udp;
var PORT = 5005;
var HOST = '127.0.0.1';
var sockInfo;

chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(function() {
    chrome.app.window.create('window.html', {
        'bounds': {
            'width': 400,
            'height': 500
        }
    });

    init();
});

function init(){
    socket.create({}, function(_sockInfo){
        sockInfo = _sockInfo;

        socket.bind(sockInfo.socketId, HOST, PORT, function(result){
            if(result < 0){
                throw "Bind failed"
            }
            console.log("Socket created and bound.");

            socket.onReceive.addListener(function(info){
                console.log('Received packet from ' + info.remoteAddress + 
                            ' : ' + info.remotePort + ', length ' + info.data.length);
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this in a Chrome App?

Comment: It wasn't before, but I've tried that now (admittedly in an extremely quick-and-dirty way) and the error remains the same. I've added my background.js file to the OP for reference.

Comment: Have you added socket permissions? Please show your app's manifest file.

Comment: Socket permissions did the trick. Thank you.